# VS Code error "The .NET CLI tools cannot be located..."

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code tells me "The .NET CLI tools cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure .NET CLI tools are installed and are on the path.". This prevents any code completion ect. can I fix this issue?

Comment: The question's not very clear - please see [ask].

Comment: It is in the Visual Studio at runtime.

Comment: You're sure you're not running Visual Studio Code?

Comment: oh, sorry it was visual studio code

Comment: did you restart VSCode after you installed CLI tools?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After you've installed [CLI tools (called ".NET SDK")](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/install), try restarting VSCode. This will allow VSCode to load the updated `$PATH` environment variable. VSCode "Reload Window" command will not help in this case.

Answer (score 24):

Sometimes the Visual Studio warning will still persist even after installing the .NET SDK. This is because a link/shortcut/alias needs to be created between the .NET executable install location and the Visual Studio path.

The executable was most likely installed in `/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet`. A symbolic link needs to be created to `usr/local/bin` for Visual Studio.

To create that link assuming the locations above use this in the Terminal:

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
```

For Ubuntu & Snap use this instead:

```
$ sudo ln -s /snap/dotnet-sdk/current/dotnet /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that VS Code looks in specific dir. So for snap users:
sudo ln -s /snap/dotnet-sdk/current/dotnet /usr/local/bin/

Answer (score 2):

on mac I added the following paths to /etc/paths

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.101
```

Answer (score 2):

File>Preferences>Settings

### "csharp.suppressDotnetInstallWarning": true,

It was worked for me
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To install the dotnet-cli with snap:

```sh
snap install code --classic
snap alias dotnet-sdk.dotnet dotnet
```

Add at the end of `.profile`:

```sh
export DOTNET_ROOT=/snap/dotnet-sdk/current export
export MSBuildSDKsPath=$DOTNET_ROOT/sdk/$(${DOTNET_ROOT}/dotnet --version)/Sdks
```

Comment: @DmitryDronov it's a hidden file in your home directory, if you put it in .bashrc or your equivalent rc file for your shell should also be fine. You might need to logout or source that file after you've done that.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux Solus 4:

Install vscode in Package manager

Install dotnet:

```
sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --classic
sudo snap alias dotnet-sdk.dotnet dotnet
sudo ln -s /snap/dotnet-sdk/current/dotnet /usr/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

For Arch

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/dotnet/sdk /usr/bin/sdk
```